# Some problem in gridslamprocess.hxx of slam_gmapping

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry to disturb you all!!

I found some problems about **gmapping** when I using **Turtlebot Package**, there is a document which named "gridslamprocess.hxx".

```
roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch
```

I already modify it, but when I  do catkin_make and create a new slam_gmapping,

I run the new one,but I didn't see have any change after I modify it.

I noticed that every time when I run gmapping, there are some information on the screen.

Ex: When scanmatch Done! it will show laser poser: x,y,z on screen. When scanmatch failed,it will use odometry. Then show lp: x,y,z op:x,y,z on screen.

So I want to get lp: op: laser pose These (x,y) information, so I'm trying to modify the source code.

When I looked in the source code, I found gridslamprocess.hxx, but i did't see any happened after me modify it

**Of course, I already compile after modifying.**

I want to get
m_lastpartpose.x  m_lastpartpose.y
m_odopose.x  m_odopose.y

[image: image description]

But I need some help..

Has anyone ever modified this file?
Thank you very much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293350/some-problem-in-gridslamprocess.hxx-of-slam_gmapping/) by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2018-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-06**:
Why did you modify the source?

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2018-06-06**:
Because I can only subscribe to /odom now, then get a pair (x,y).
I also need another pair of (x,y) to compare.

So I noticed that every time when I run gmapping, there are some information on the screen.

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2018-06-06**:
Ex:
When scanmatch Done! it will show laser poser: x,y,z on screen.
When scanmatch failed,it will use odometry.
Then show lp: x,y,z op:x,y,z on screen.

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2018-06-06**:
So I want to get lp: op: laser pose These (x,y) information, so I'm trying to modify the source code.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-06**:
Are you saying that you are using gmapping for localization?

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2018-06-07**:
yes,I am using turtlebot and use gmapping to do SLAM

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-07**:
Please don't use images to post text. Images can't be searched/copy-pasted. Please update your question with a copy and pasted of your code instead.

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2018-06-07**:
Thank you~~  I'll get what I want now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically, the `gmapping` package is used for [mapping an environment](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping):

> Using slam_gmapping, you can create a 2-D occupancy grid map (like a building floorplan) from laser and pose data collected by a mobile robot.

and other packages such as [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) are used for localization. Some packages, such as [google cartographer](http://wiki.ros.org/cartographer), do simulatenous mapping and localization. So, you should either

- use a mapping package (e.g., `gmapping`) and a separate localization package (e.g., `amcl`)
- use a package that does simultaneous mapping and localization (e.g., Google `cartographer`)

As a side note, it is not a good idea to modify the source of packages that you don't control. If/when that package gets updated any changes that you made will be lost when it's updated.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2018-06-07**:
I change slam_gmapping.cpp now, and i get what i want, thank you!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-07**:
Great. Can you please click on the checkmark to mark the answer as correct?